# Node Module path to relative files

Tags: node.js, path, fs, dirname, npm-link

So I have written a short node module (module1) as a wrapper for a binary (.exe) that can be called via command line.

This is how I get the path to the binary to execute the .exe with `execFilePromised`.
It works in my module1.

```
const __dirname = fs.realpathSync('.');
const mpqEditorLocation = path.resolve(__dirname, './mpq/MPQEditor.exe');
```

**Problem:**
When I import module1 with `npm link ../<module1>` into another node project the path is not correctly set to the `.exe` since this resides in my `node_modules` folder and not at `<otherproject>/mpq/MPQEditor.exe`

How can I make the `__dirname` relative to the actual file not the project execution directory?

Answer (score 0):

So I found my solution do not use 
`npm link`!

Use `npm install <absolute path to your package>` instead.

I just printed my location with `pwd`and then installed it there.

That way I could refactor the pathing to:

```
const mpqEditorLocation = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'mpq', 'MPQEditor.exe');
```

worked since then :)